# How do I report an issue with nfs-kernel-server when I have a different version installed

Tags: kernel, nfs

On 10/19 I upgraded my servers to Ubuntu 17.10.  I have file systems NFS exported to mostly Linux clients but also one antique SunOS 4.1.4 client.  Prior to upgrade to Artful, Zesty was working file.  After upgrade, the SunOS client could no longer mount the exported file system.  It said, "Wrong program version".  But using `rpcinfo -p server`, it showed versions 1-4 available so it should have been able to mount version 3.  I replaced the `nfs-kernel-server` and `nfs-common` package with those from Zesty and things worked again so it is not a kernel issue but definitely one of these two packages.  Since I've already reverted, if I try to report with Apport, it reports the Zesty version but Zesty works fine.

Comment: Roll back temporarily to the newer packages, report bug, revert to zesty again?

Comment: File a bug report against SunOS nfs-client as Ubuntu side is working.

Comment: No, Ubuntu Zesty worked, Ubuntu Artful does not.  SunOS hasn't changed since 1992, so no upgrades going to come from there.  Either someone needs to fix it or I'm stuck with the Zesty packages.

Comment: Temporarily rolling back not an option as these servers are critical but it occurred to me that what I can do is make a virtual machine, export a file system under Zesty, mount it on the SunOS box, then upgrade it and file a bug report when it breaks.